# PostgreSQL logical replication copy_data false not working

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

I upped database from backup and need subscribe for tables that data existis in it.
So I created subscription with copy_data false and anyway got error

**ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.**

Postgresql version 12

Creating subscription via pgadmin 6.

Comment: Do you have a question? I'm not sure what you are hoping to get from this.

Comment: Hard to help you since you're the only one who knows how to handle data that violates your constraints. However, if you do want to allow this data to get into your database, you should drop the constraint. But there is definitely no problem with the logical replication, that works fine.

Comment: I thought with copy_data false it wouldn't copy existing data thus existing data would not be problem.Maybe I understand "copy_data=false" wrong or mb it is known bug.